# C2061 error in c++

Tags: c++

I know that this error is common, but i've been trying to fix to for 4 hours, and simply do not understand why it occures.

file that gives an error "shape.h":

```
#ifndef __shape_atd__
#define __shape_atd__
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
namespace simple_shapes {
    class shape
    {
        public:
            enum colors { Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, DarkBlue, Violet };
            colors color;
            static shape* In(int lengt, Creator *c[], istringstream &ifst);         
            virtual void InData(istringstream &) = 0;
            virtual void Out(ofstream &) = 0;
            shape() {};
    }
```

this all worked fine before I added "Creator *[]c" in the "In" method. Now it refuses to compile, with an error C2061: syntax error : identifier "Creator".

Here is the "Creator.h" file:

```
#ifndef __creator_atd__
#define __creator_atd__
namespace simple_shapes {
    class Creator {
    public:
        virtual shape* createShape() = 0;
    };
}
#endif
```

I've read that this error occures because of circular header dependency, but in my case I don't have them. Also, "Creator.h" is not mentioned in any other files in the program except its children.

Comment: You need to have a forward declare of `shape` for the `Creator`class.

Comment: Incidentally, names starting with a double underscore are reserved for the compiler/standard library. Don't use them for your include guards.

Comment: @user0042 actually forward declaration on `Creator` in `shape` class helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either include `shape.h` in `Creator.h` or forward declare `shape` in `Creator.h`. For example -

```
#ifndef __creator_atd__
#define __creator_atd__
namespace simple_shapes {
    class shape; // forward declaration
    class Creator {
    public:
        virtual shape* createShape() = 0;
    };
}
#endif
```

Another example with including `shape.h` is given below -

```
#ifndef __creator_atd__
#define __creator_atd__

#include "shape.h"

namespace simple_shapes {
    class Creator {
    public:
        virtual shape* createShape() = 0;
    };
}
#endif
```

Comment: Huh, it finally compiled and worked after I added forward declaration, but not this one. I added the declaration of the `Creator` class to the `shape.h`.